# How to control user to access my data?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model like this

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cost_code =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    total_cost = models.IntegerField()

def  __unicode__(self):
    return self.class_name
```

Now when if the admin calls i need to display all the details, if the class teacher calls i need to display only perticular class details. Here how can i create view and control this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at python decorators.

Comment: You can grant different rights to the users in your views, not in your model. You can use the decorator @login_required for function based views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has an excellent full fledged permission system. Read the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization).

A simplistic example would be, to create user groups, assign relevant permissions to the groups, and then, add users to these groups. This can easily be done from the admin. Then, to check for permission, use the helper methods on user, like `user.has_perm('foo.add_bar')` or the decorator for views.

Answer (score 1):

You need `QuerySet Managers` to perform this task. A full fledged documentation is given [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/)

Answer (score 1):

You can manage it manually using decorator.To determines whether or not a user has permission to see a view or not.

If your qustion is about to related to restrict some of data to specific kind of user, have a look at `user_passes_test`

Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test)